# what field should I use for password?

Tags: python, django-models

I am using python version 3.5 and django version 1.11.
I wanted to know what field should I use for pasword

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    repeat_password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,null=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    alternative_address = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    join_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    paid_salary_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, extend the Django [`User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) instead, and add those extra fields to your `Employee` class. You can equally override or define new methods.

See [Extending the existing `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). Infact, the example provided in the docs is an `Employee` class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Really, why downvote? I agree! "Don't reinvent the wheel, extend the Django User model..."